# How to select an element after creating it with javascript when the page is already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a "Add new shipment" button that creates a whole div that includes like 4 fields and a 2nd submit button under all that. that 2nd submit button is supposed to post this new div onto the page and add it to db but I am having trouble selecting the fields and selecting the new submit button. I think this is because  the page is already loaded from the beginning, so this new div cannot be selected anymore? Here is my HTML that is created from the "Add new shipment" button:

```
// adds new shipment
const ADD_SHIPMENT_GRAY = function (){
    return 
    <div class="shipment panel panel-success col-xs-2">
        <div class="shipmentblocks row">
            <div class="idzone btn-block classificationline">
                <!--  label  ---->
                <input type="text" class="customer btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-12" placeholder="Customer"><strong id="customertext"></strong></button>
                <!--  contents -->
                <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-12" placeholder="File Number">
                    <strong class="boldedlabels" id="filenumber"></strong>
                    <span class="labelcontents"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="etd btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-12" placeholder="ETD" id="etd">
                    <strong class="boldedlabels"></strong>
                    <span class="labelcontents" id="etddatepicker">ETD</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="eta btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-12" placeholder="ETA" id="eta">
                    <strong class="boldedlabels"></strong>
                    <span class="labelcontents" id="etadatepicker">ETA</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="shipmentsubmission btn btn-default btn-xs col-xs-12">
                    <strong class="boldedlabels eta"></strong>
                    <span class="labelcontents" id="submitnewshipment">Submit</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>;
}
```

Here is my javascript code that executes the above code:

```
const SCRIPTS = function (){
$(function(){
    const addshipment = $("#addshipment"),
          labelsubmission = $(".labelsubmission"),
          shipment = $(".shipment"),
          shipmentblocks = $(".shipmentblocks"),
          idzone = $(".idzone"),
          etd = $(".etd"),
          addsubmit = $("#addsubmit"),
          zzz = $("#zzz"), // div to keep maximum new shipment as 1
          submitnewshipment = $("#submitnewshipment"), // button to submit the new shipment 


    // Add New Shipment
    addshipment.click(() => { // in console, indexes closer to 0 (ex: index [0]) = newer
        //$(".shipment:first").before(ADD_SHIPMENT_GRAY());
        // add new shipment green block
        $("#zzz").html(ADD_SHIPMENT_GRAY());
    });
})
}
```

Comment: for starters you can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition.

Comment: You do have some broken HTML. There are `</button>` missing their openers after the first and second inputs. Also, is there a particular reason why the HTML must be placed inside a JS function?

Comment: Thank you. Oh and I created the html in javascript function  so that it creates a new html element in javascript because I don't know how to clone a whole html element if it was in html. Like I know I can do $(selector).clone() for jQuery but I don't know how I can use that to reset the values when I do that

Answer (score 2):

You are creating dynamic data which requires you to use `.on` in jquery, otherwise it will not find the element.

Also dont repeat `id`'s make it a class instead

```
$(document).on('click', '.addshipment', function () { 
    // in console, indexes closer to 0 (ex: index [0]) = newer
    //$(".shipment:first").before(ADD_SHIPMENT_GRAY());
    // add new shipment green block
    $("#zzz").html(ADD_SHIPMENT_GRAY());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/